# Let $F$ in $(N)$ be the set of all finite subsets of $N$. Prove that $F$ in $(N)$ is countably infinite.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ be the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\mathcal{F}$ in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is countably infinite. Where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers and $\mathcal{P}(\cdot)$ denotes the power set.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hint : We have a union of countable many countable subsets, namely the sets with $0,1,2,3,\cdots$ elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The set $F(\Bbb N_0)$ is the set of all finite words over the alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$, i.e., $\Sigma^*$.

Take the sequence of primes $(p_0,p_1,\ldots)$.

The mapping $f:\Sigma^* \rightarrow \Bbb N_0:w_0w_1\ldots w_k\mapsto p_0^{w_0}\cdots p_k^{w_k}$ is injective.

For instance: empty word is mapped to $0$, $1010$ is mapped to $p_0p_2$ and so on.